# Unit Tests assertionFailure

Tags: swift, unit-testing, xctest

I'm unit testing:

```
func testParseFakeDeeplinkSuccess() {
    let fakeDeeplink = "fakeDeeplink"
    let url = touchManager?.handleTouch(["deeplink": fakeDeeplink as NSSecureCoding])
    XCTAssertNotNil(url)
}
```

which will result in "assertionFailure("3DTouch not trackable")"

```
    func handleTouch(_ userInfo: [String: NSSecureCoding]?) -> URL? {
    if let shortcut = userInfo?["deeplink"] as? String,
       let url = URL(string: shortcut) {

        switch shortcut {
        default:
            assertionFailure("3DTouch not trackable")
        }

        return url
    }

    return nil
}
```

What can I use in my unit tests to tests this properly?

Comment: You need to use a valid URL. `"fakeDeeplink"` is not a valid URL, so your if-let fails.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Not really, it will result in "which will result in "assertionFailure("3DTouch not trackable")"". It's written on the question

Comment: You also need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make it on-topic. Your code in its current form cannot be compiled, because you didn't include the definitions for `Keys` or `Deeplink`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor done. Can you now remove the -1 and close request, please?

Comment: @bruno You are still missing `Keys` (and `deeplink` from the test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hitting the assertion error because that's the branch your code reaches once it's evaluated.

```swift
if let shortcut = userInfo?["deeplink"] as? String, let url = URL(string: shortcut) {
  // 1. The branch is taken, unwrapped `shortcut`, it's value is "fakeDeeplink"

  switch shortcut {
  default:
    // 2. This is the only branch in the switch, so this case is always executed.
    assertionFailure("3DTouch not trackable")
  }
}
```

You might only be seeing a crash in your tests (and not in a production build of your app) because `assertionFailure` will have no effect in the default `-O` optimization mode used in RELEASE builds.
Tests, by default, will be compiled for DEBUG which uses the `-Onone` optimization mode causing assertions to trigger a crash.

If you want to handle an error condition without trapping, you should either return `nil` or use a throwing method instead:

```swift
struct TouchNotTrackableError: Error { }

func handleTouch(_ userInfo: [String: NSSecureCoding]?) throws -> URL? {
    if let shortcut = userInfo?["deeplink"] as? String,
       let url = URL(string: shortcut) {

        switch shortcut {
        default:
            throw TouchNotTrackableError()
        }

        return url
    }

    return nil
}
```

Then you can test if the method throws.

```swift
func testParseFakeDeeplinkSuccess() {
    let fakeDeeplink = "fakeDeeplink"
    XCTAssertThrowsError(try touchManager?.handleTouch(["deeplink": fakeDeeplink as NSSecureCoding]))
}
```

Comment: Let me add that `assertionFailure` is not for unit tests. It's production code stating "This should never happen, stop the program now." …In case you were confusing it with XCTest assertions.

Comment: Let me further add that `assertionFailure` only does anything in debug builds, and since production code is normally the result of a release build, it has nothing to do with production code, except indirectly through any bugs that are fixed as a result of its being triggered in debug builds.  I think @JonReid used "production code" to simply refer to actual program code as opposed to unit test code.  Neither @Bradley Mackey nor OP seems confused on this point, so I guess it's for others reading these comments.